# Google MAP API v3: computeDistanceBetween method and distance in metric form

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to calculate the direct distance between to positions in metric form. (ie: from A to B in kilometers).

I didn't understand what [computeDistanceBetween](http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html#Distance) method returns in units.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's in meters. To convert to kilometers divide by <s>1024</s>1000, [obviously](http://jsfiddle.net/qy7yr/).

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
    Moscow, Leningrad
); // 679601 m
```

By the way, the underlying code of this library method is based on the [Haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Comment: Nice, I was just about to post that link.  I prefer to use the Haversine formula instead so I can switch between units on the fly.  As far as I can tell you cannot change the units with the Google method.

Comment: Oh yes, and the third optional parameter to the `computeDistanceBetween` is the radius of the spherical body (might be another planet). It defaults to Earth's equatorial radius, of course.

Comment: @bweaver, we are using the Havesine formula function separately to avoid loading Google's geometry library.